# Return only rows with maximum key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, top-n

I have two columns in my table:

```
- RECE_KEY
- INVE_KEY
```

I want to return only rows for INVE_KEY where RECE_KEY is max.

Example:

INVE_KEY = 1 is included in RECE_KEY = 1,2,3.
Max RECE_KEY in this example is 3, so correct result would be:

```
+----------+----------+
| RECE_KEY | INVE_KEY |
+----------+----------+
|        3 |        1 |
|        3 |        1 |
|        3 |        1 |
|        3 |        1 |
+----------+----------+
```

For the whole table expected result would be:

```
+----------+----------+
| RECE_KEY | INVE_KEY |
+----------+----------+
|        3 |        1 |
|        3 |        1 |
|        3 |        1 |
|        3 |        1 |
|        3 |        4 |
|        5 |        5 |
|        5 |        5 |
|        5 |        5 |
+----------+----------+
```

I've tried to solve this grouping and where conditions but without success. I guess I am missing something?

Example table is below:

```
DECLARE @JEREIN TABLE
(
RECE_KEY INT,
INVE_KEY INT
)

INSERT INTO @JEREIN 
VALUES(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(2,1),(2,1),(3,1),(3,1),(3,1),(3,1),(2,4),(2,4),(3,4),(3,5),(3,5),(5,5),(5,5),(5,5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first choice would be `ranking` function, but you can also use corretalted suqbuery  :

```
select t.*
from @JEREIN t
where RECE_KEY = (select max(t1.RECE_KEY) from @JEREIN t1 where t1.INVE_KEY = t.INVE_KEY);
```

However, you can also use `dense_rank` with *ties* clause :

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from @JEREIN t
order by dense_rank() over (partition by INVE_KEY order by RECE_KEY desc);
```

Comment: The first one is very good, because it can be used in any subquery. The second one can be a problem in subqueries because subquery does not allow usage of order by without TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML specified. Thanks a lot. If you have any good link for techniques you've used above please provide.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `rank` window function to find the top row per `inve_key`:

```
SELECT rece_key, inve_key
FROM   (SELECT rece_key, inve_key, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY inve_key ORDER BY rece_key DESC) AS rk
        FROM   @JEREIN) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: @FrenkyB you can start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017